# Morton index from 2D point with floats

Tags: c++, algorithm, z-order-curve

I have a 2D point that looks something like this:

```
class Point
{
    float m_x, m_y;

public:

    int mortonIndex()
    {
        // what would go here?
    }
};
```

I know what to do with integers, but I need to use floats. I also want to avoid scaling for any particular grid size.

### Related page on Wikipedia:

[Morton index, or Z order curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve)

Comment: What's a Morton index?  Yes, I could google it, but maybe you could put that in your question, so that I don't have to.

Comment: They're also known as "Z indices" or "points on a Lebesgue curve".

Comment: Seems to be a straightforward question to me. If you don't know what a Morton index is, you don't need to bother yourself with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways of looking at this:

- A `float` being a 256-bit number, (or similarly, a `double` as a 2100-bit number, implemented [here][1]).
- A `float` being a weird 32-bit integer.

I'll use the latter, as it's easier to implement.

This approach takes advantage of the fact that IEEE `float`s were originally designed to be compatible with old integer-only database engines, allowing them to treat floating point numbers as 1s complement integers.

More precisely, in the 1s complement sense, the ordering of floating point values respects that of integers of the same width (in fact, directly adding 1 to a punned float will give you the adjacent value with larger absolute magnitude**).

```
class Point
{
    float m_x, m_y;

    // This assert is not correct when the floating point model
    // is not IEEE-compliant, float is not 32-bit, or both.
    //
    // Such things are hard to find, so we'll just assume
    // mostly-sane hardware.
    //
    static_assert(
        (sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)) &&
        (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT == 32) &&
        (sizeof(long long)*CHAR_BIT == 64),
        "We need 32-bit ints and floats, and 64-bit long longs!"
        );

public:

    // So we don't lose any information, we need 2x the width.
    // After all, we're cramming two 32-bit numbers into a single value.
    // Lossiness here would mean a container would need to implement
    // a binning strategy.
    //
    // Higher dimensions would require an array, obviously.
    //
    // Also, we're not going to modify the point, so make this a const routine.
    //
    long long mortonIndex() const
    {
        // Pun the x and y coordinates as integers: Just re-interpret the bits.
        //
        auto ix = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned &>(this->m_x);
        auto iy = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned &>(this->m_y);

        // Since we're assuming 2s complement arithmetic (99.99% of hardware today),
        // we'll need to convert these raw integer-punned floats into
        // their corresponding integer "indices".

        // Smear their sign bits into these for twiddling below.
        //
        const auto ixs = static_cast<int>(ix) >> 31;
        const auto iys = static_cast<int>(iy) >> 31;

        // This is a combination of a fast absolute value and a bias.
        //
        // We need to adjust the values so -FLT_MAX is close to 0.
        //
        ix = (((ix & 0x7FFFFFFFL) ^ ixs) - ixs) + 0x7FFFFFFFL;
        iy = (((iy & 0x7FFFFFFFL) ^ iys) - iys) + 0x7FFFFFFFL;

        // Now we have -FLT_MAX close to 0, and FLT_MAX close to UINT_MAX,
        // with everything else in-between.
        //
        // To make this easy, we'll work with x and y as 64-bit integers.
        //
        long long xx = ix;
        long long yy = iy;

        // Dilate and combine as usual...

        xx = (xx | (xx << 16)) & 0x0000ffff0000ffffLL;
        yy = (yy | (yy << 16)) & 0x0000ffff0000ffffLL;

        xx = (xx | (xx <<  8)) & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffLL;
        yy = (yy | (yy <<  8)) & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffLL;

        xx = (xx | (xx <<  4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fLL;
        yy = (yy | (yy <<  4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fLL;

        xx = (xx | (xx <<  2)) & 0x3333333333333333LL;
        yy = (yy | (yy <<  2)) & 0x3333333333333333LL;

        xx = (xx | (xx <<  1)) & 0x5555555555555555LL;
        yy = (yy | (yy <<  1)) & 0x5555555555555555LL;

        return xx | (yy << 1);
    }
};
```

Note that the vertices of the resulting curve have the same distribution as positions in 2D floating point space.

This can be a problem if you intend to use this with an on-disk structure, as clustering near coordinate axes or the origin can cause range queries to cross a large number of boxes near them. Otherwise, IMO, it is a reasonably performant alternative to generating uniform indices (and its devoid of branches!).

**Special handling is needed for infinities and NaN, but you get the idea.

Comment: What are the magic numbers for? I mean "0x0000ffff0000ffffLL" and so on...

Comment: Combined with the shifting in the same statement, they mask out half of the value we didn't want to dilate at that step. If you do this by hand for a value of, say all 1s, you'll notice that this "spreads" the bits out.

Comment: The examples at http://asgerhoedt.dk/?p=276 help understand the magic numbers.